# PulseAudio does not detect sound cards on boot

Tags: boot, sound, pulseaudio

During the boot process it seems like i have no sound cards. The output of `pactl list cards` is blank in my `rc.local` script. `set-default-sink` and `set-default-source` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` give error `Sink/Source <name> does not exist`. However as soon as i boot and login  i see devices in settings, all cards are available and running `pulseaudio -k` sets the correct defaults specified in `default.pa`. What could be the problem?